# Comparar string[] com string

Tags: c#, string, selenium-webdriver

Tentei assim:

```
IWebElement descriptionTextXPath = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ng-include[1]/section/ul/li[1]/div/div/article/h4"));
            String h4 = descriptionTextXPath.Text;
            Assert.AreEqual("Controle\n" + "Básico", h4);
```

Retorno:

```
Message:Assert.AreEqual.Failed
Expected:<Controle Básico>.Atual:<Controle Básico>
```

O intuito é afirmar que o "Controle básico" existe na tela. Segue a estrutura html onde se encontra:

```
<h4 class="simulation-plan-name ng-binding">

Controle 
<span class="simulation-plan-type ng-binding">Básico</span>
</h4>
```

Tentei ser o mais claro possível, vocês podem, por favor, me ajudar ?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer comprar. Coloque um exemplo do que tentou e o resultado esperado.

Comment: é igual a perguntar como comparar um `int[]` (ex: `{1, 2, 3}`) com um `int` (ex: `1`). Não podem ser comparados, são diferentes. Tens de converter o `int[]` num `int`, ou o inverso.

Comment: Já tentou fazer um `String words = s.Split(' ').Join("");` e comparar com o `descriptionTextXPath `?

Comment: Então, quero fazer uma assertiva e ver se são exatamente iguais, "Controle Básico" que está na tela e "Controle Básico" que criei. Mas a assertiva não funciona. Se o caso, é deixar dois tipos iguais String - String. Como faria isso e o que utilizaria para verificar se a condição de igualdade é verdadeira ?

Comment: Segue o que tentei:  IWebElement h4element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ng-include[1]/section/ul/li[1]/div/div/article/h4"));
            String descriptionTextXPath = h4element.Text;
            
            
            String s = "Controle Básico";
            String[] words = s.Split(' ');               Não sei o equal que utilizaria neste caso, mas tentei Assert.AreEquals(words,descriptionTextXPath); Mas não deu certo.

Comment: Se tu queres deixar os dois tipos igual a `string` não faz sentido fazer `String[] words = s.Split(' ');`.

Comment: @AndersonAlves por favor, edite a sua questão e coloque o código nela. Nos comentários fica praticamente impossível de entender.

Comment: Tentei: 

String s = "Controle Básico";
String words = s.Split(' ').Join("");



Aponta o seguinte erro:

'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Join' and extension method 'Join' accepting of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)

Tentei declarar com using System.Array;
Não deu certo.

Comment: Bom resumindo, quero comparar esses dois caras:                            String descriptionTextXPath = h4element.Text;
String[] words = s.Split(' ');          
Sei que são diferentes, a idéia era converter um deles e depois, com os 2 iguais, compara com algum Assert.

Comment: A questao e': como e' queres converter um array de strings numa string? Se o array de strings for `{ hello, world }`, qual deveria ser o resultado? Esta e' uma pergunta para ti, nao para nos. So' tu sabes como queres fazer a comparacao.

Comment: String s = "Controle Básico";
            String[] words = s.Split(' ');
            Console.WriteLine(words);

Comment: IWebElement h4element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ng-include[1]/section/ul/li[1]/div/div/article/h4"));
String descriptionTextXPath = h4element.Text;
Console.WriteLine(descriptionTextXPath);

            String s = "Controle Básico";
            String[] words = s.Split(' ');

            foreach (string word in words)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(word);
             }   // Pessoal coloquei dentro desse foreach e transformei para string os dois valores são iguais "Controle Básico" com quebra de linha. Resta saber como comparo agora?

Comment: IWebElement descriptionTextXPath = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ng-include[1]/section/ul/li[1]/div/div/article/h4"));
            String h4 = descriptionTextXPath.Text;
            Assert.AreEqual("Controle\n" + "Básico", h4);

Answer (score 2):

Bom, ainda não sei se consegui entender o que você precisa fazer, mas presumi que queres comparar o valor que tens numa `string` com todos os valores de um `array de string`.

Para fazer isso, você deve usar o método **estático** [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) para **unir** todos os valores do `array` em uma `string` e depois comparar com o valor que já está na `string`.

O método [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) recebe como **primeiro** parâmetro o separador dos valores do array e como **segundo** parâmetro o array cujos valores você pretende "unir".

```
string[] arrStr = {"Controle", "Básico"};
string str = "Controle Básico";
var str2 = string.Join(" ", arrStr);

if(str == str2)
    //Essa condição será verdadeira
```